# Font color in photoshop and css

Tags: html, css, colors, photoshop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmtfc.png

I set the same color in photoshop and then in css. In photoshop (left) is just green but in css (right) is green, blue, red, etc...
The color is same (##6a6635). How can I set in css the colors like in photoshop?

Comment: Can you post your css or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

thats not a problem it is the same color, just the graphic engine of the browser built it lil bit different from the engine of the photoshop, also u may be interesting read this:
http://usabilitypost.com/2008/07/30/photoshop-color-profiles-for-web-images/

Comment: I Think he is talking about the CSS of his webpage, not saving a image for web in Photoshop. The link is very useful though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a kind of sub-pixel antialiasing that allows for sharper, clearer text. You can't disable it, that's how it's supposed to work. You're not supposed to take a screenshot and then scale it up - if you zoom into the webpage, the antialiasing is recalculated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To translate your PS colors more accurately to CSS, why not try a tool like Project Parfait that Adobe recently put out? https://projectparfait.adobe.com/  You upload a PSD and can then select elements of your PSD to find its CSS or extract your assets. It's sometimes hard to get the exact color or gradient info in a comp from PS (especially for those of us who don't work in PS every day) and Project Parfait will go and grab that information for you.